# Returning python error while running docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

I am using `Fedora Linux 38`, and Docker version is `Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc`.
Trying to run my Golang code through docker-compose, it giving error with python error log

First I ran `sudo systemctl start docker`, and then see status `sudo systemctl status docker`

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-07-06 15:36:12 WITA; 1h 28min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 6250 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 19
     Memory: 25.1M
        CPU: 1.129s
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─6250 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Jul 06 15:36:11 fedora dockerd[6250]: time="2023-07-06T15:36:11.945573688+08:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jul 06 15:36:11 fedora dockerd[6250]: time="2023-07-06T15:36:11.951059455+08:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
Jul 06 15:36:12 fedora dockerd[6250]: time="2023-07-06T15:36:12.201788778+08:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
Jul 06 15:36:12 fedora dockerd[6250]: time="2023-07-06T15:36:12.219682126+08:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
Jul 06 15:36:12 fedora dockerd[6250]: time="2023-07-06T15:36:12.575897504+08:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
Jul 06 15:36:12 fedora dockerd[6250]: time="2023-07-06T15:36:12.693718363+08:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jul 06 15:36:12 fedora dockerd[6250]: time="2023-07-06T15:36:12.770247971+08:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=659604f graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.2
Jul 06 15:36:12 fedora dockerd[6250]: time="2023-07-06T15:36:12.770335275+08:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jul 06 15:36:12 fedora dockerd[6250]: time="2023-07-06T15:36:12.808876169+08:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
Jul 06 15:36:12 fedora systemd[1]: Started docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Then `sudo dockerd --debug` got

```
INFO[2023-07-06T17:09:52.227973747+08:00] Starting up                                  
failed to start daemon, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid: process with PID 6250 is still running
```

After that I go to my working directory and run `docker-compose up -d` and it return error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1286, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1332, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1281, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1041, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 979, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 718, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1286, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1332, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1281, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1041, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/http/client.py", line 979, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 547, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.29.2', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

I am trying to reinstall docker-compose but it still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall, and try official docker-ce
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/fedora/

Answer (score 0):

It means the previous PID file of Docker service is still available, so the Docker service it can't start the service because one process id is already present. To prevent this error, you have to remove the previous PID file and then try to start your service.

Delete the .pid file with the command:

```
rm /var/run/docker.pid
```

Restart Docker:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```